# eliminating parameters

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-series

Let
$$
x= \cos(t) - \sin(t),\quad  y= 2 \sin(t).
$$
I have to eliminate the parameter t. I would normally do this by solving for $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ and then use

$$\sin^2(t)  +\cos^2(t)   = 1,$$

but due to there being both a sine and cosine in the equation for $x$ I don't know how to solve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin(t)=\frac{y}2$$

$$\cos(t) = x+\frac{y}2$$

Hence, we have

$$\frac{y^2}4+\left( x+\frac{y}2\right)^2=1$$

$$x^2+xy+\frac{y^2}2=1$$

which is an ellipse.